# Find Xuggle from Applet

Tags: java, applet, xuggle

How can I make it possible for a Java applet find xuggle path? I was thing in making an installer wrapper and save a hidden file on user's path ( e.g. .myAppConfig.txt) but if I could find a better approach it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version of xuggle (5.4) don't need to have native libraries installed first, you can use xuggle jar in applets, it is large but possible. I used a local cache implementation, so full download only occurs one time.

Answer (score 0):

Xuggler wiki claims, it's impossible (at least for now): [Can I use Xuggler with Java Webstart or as an Applet?](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_use_Xuggler_with_Java_Webstart_or_as_an_Applet.3F)

Comment: I am using Xuggle IN an Applet. It works fine. The user installs xuggle first, then the applet works. The only downside is that on Mac, the user has to manually set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH system variable. I am thinking of writing a wrapper installer to set that variable.